# NHibernate 2.* mapping files: how to define nullable DateTime type (DateTime?)?

Tags: nhibernate, datetime, nhibernate-mapping, nullable

I know one of the breaking changes with NHibernate 2.* is that the NHibernate.Nullables are no longer supported. Therefore, what do you use in your mapping file to map the nullable DateTime? type? For i.e.:

Understandably doesn't work:

```
<property name="CreateDate" column="CreateDate" type="DateTime?" not-null="false" />
```

And no longer supported:

```
<property name="ModifiedDate" column="ModifiedDate" type="Nullables.NHibernate.NullableDateTimeType, Nullables.NHibernate" not-null="false"/>
```

I know it must be so obvious, but I'm not finding it!

Answer is as simple as:
NHibernate will reflect over the class in question and discover that the property's reflected type is DateTime? all on its own.

Thanks @Justice!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
<property name="CreatedDate" />
```

- NHibernate will reflect over the class in question and discover that the property's reflected type is `DateTime?` all on its own.
- NHibernate will assume the column name is by default the same as the property name, unless you tell it otherwise.
- NHibernate will assume that any property is nullable (`not-null="false"`) unless you tell it otherwise.

If you really want, it should be something like ...

```
<property name="CreatedDate" type="System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTime, mscorlib]], mscorlib" />
```

Comment: Much thanks. I know number two and three, but can't believe I'd never seen the first one - that simple, eh?

Comment: FWIW, this is a whole lot easier using something like the mapping attributes, where this would just be `[Property(Name="CreatedDate", TypeType=typeof(DateTime?))]`